# Why there was no trial for Michael Cohen

Tags: united-states, trial, sentencing

I am reading in the news that Michale Cohen will be sentenced today, however, I haven't seen any information about trial.

Is that because conviction is related to [perjury plea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Cohen_(lawyer)#Senate_perjury_plea), hence there is no need for trial and process is skipped right to the sentencing?

Or is there special process of trial when special counsel / prosecutor is involved?

Comment: Generally, a trial is held to resolve some controversy.  In a criminal case, that would happen when the government claims the defendant is guilty and the defendant claims that he's not.  In this case, Cohen has pleaded guilty, meaning that both he and the government agree he is guilty.  There is no disagreement for a trial to resolve.

Answer (score 11):

Cohen plead guilty to a number of charges. If you plead guilty with any charges, then there is no need to go forward with a trial.

Comment: This is the right answer, but it could be expanded upon to explain why it is correct.

Comment: It might also help to explain why someone would just plead guilty (because you generally get a reduced sentence that way).